# Some emojis not showing on PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, emoji

I have a table that needs to display some emojis in the table. You'll see from my first screenshot, it displays the football emoji correctly and the star correctly, but the ️ symbol shows as '?'.

[image: screenshot1]

Having read through Stack Overflow for solutions it was suggested that I change all the collations to "utf8mb4_unicode_ci" which I have done, but still no joy.

[image: screenshot2]

Can anyone help?

Screenshots attached to show the layout and structure as well as how the csv looks from where it obtains the data.

[image: screenshot3]

If I insert a row in manually using SQL, it displays properly, so maybe some sort of find&replace instructions in the SQL would do the job?

(I am very basic on SQL knowledge having not really used it for 3 years).

Comment: Sounds like a client-side / display issue, specifically with PHPMyAdmin. Is the problem present when you use the data in your actual application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Nah, on WordPress it shows the "?" unfortunately